# How can I set variables in Ruby with an if statement on one line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With Ruby, how can I set a variable based on a condition? Something like:

```
dog_name = params[:dog][:name] if params[:dog]
```

And then dog_name just wouldn't be set if params[:dog] wasn't set.

Right now I'm getting an error if params[:dog] is nil.

Comment: You must have a typo, because your line of code as written works just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `&&` operator:

```
dog_name = params[:dog] && params[:dog][:name]
```

So now `dog_name` will be `nil` if `params[:dog]` does not exist, else it will be the value of `params[:dog][:name]`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing should work.

I imagine that `params[:dog]` is not actually nil. I bet it's an empty string (or empty hash). (You can check on this by outputting params[:dog].inspect to the log or stdout.)

Rails has a method `blank?` that tests for nil, empty string, empty collection.

Try:

```
dog_name = params[:dog][:name] if !params[:dog].blank?
```

Or:

```
dog_name = params[:dog][:name] unless params[:dog].blank?
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could use the &&= operator:

```
dog_name = params.has_key(:dog)
dog_name &&= params[:dog].has_key(:name)
dog_name &&= params[:dog][:name]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dog_name = params[:dog][:name] if params.has_key?(:dog) && params[:dog].has_key(:name)
```

What error are you getting when params[:dog] is nil?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this:

```
dog_name = params[:dog][:name] unless params[:dog].nil?
```